# Vue StripeCheckout - Error when routing to another component

Tags: typescript, vue.js, stripe-payments, vuejs3

I would like to use the `StripeCheckout` component within my Vue application. To do so I've copied their example code (and updated it to use the composition API) from [here](https://docs.vuestripe.com/vue-stripe/stripe-checkout/one-time-payment).

If I route to my subscribe component it works fine. I can click the subscribe button and pay. However, if I try routing to a different component after the subscribe page has been rendered it throws an error when trying to unmount the `StripeCheckout` component.

**Exception**

```
Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '__asyncLoader')
    at isAsyncWrapper (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:2243:1)
    at unmount (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6061:1)
    at unmountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6183:1)
    at unmount (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6068:1)
    at unmountChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6212:1)
    at unmount (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6086:1)
    at unmountComponent (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6183:1)
    at unmount (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6068:1)
    at unmountChildren (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6212:1)
    at unmount (runtime-core.esm-bundler.js?d2dd:6086:1)
```

**Subscribe Component**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <stripe-checkout
      ref="checkoutRef"
      mode="subscription"
      :pk="publishKey"
      :line-items="lineItems"
      :success-url="successUrl"
      :cancel-url="cancelUrl"
      @loading="(v) => (this.loading = v)"
    />
    <button @click="submit">Subscribe!</button>
  </div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" setup>
import { StripeCheckout } from "@vue-stripe/vue-stripe";
import { ref } from "vue";
import { EnvironmentVariableManager } from "@/utils/environment-variable-manager";

const publishKey = EnvironmentVariableManager.getStripePublishableKey();
const loading = ref(false);
const lineItems = [
  {
    price: "price_1MLUEMLQEklYWrzRVqxFJqt8",
    quantity: 1,
  },
];

const successUrl = EnvironmentVariableManager.getUrl() + "/subscribe";
const cancelUrl = EnvironmentVariableManager.getUrl() + "/subscribe";

const checkoutRef = ref<StripeCheckout | null>(null);

const submit = () => {
  if (checkoutRef.value) {
    checkoutRef.value.redirectToCheckout();
  } else {
    console.error("Checkout ref not found");
  }
};
</script>
```

**Router**

```
const routes = [{
    path: "/subscribe",
    name: "Subscribe",
    component: HomeView,
    children: [{ name: "Subscribe", path: "", component: Subscribe }],
  },
];

const router = createRouter({
  history: createWebHistory(process.env.BASE_URL),
  routes,
});
```

I've noticed with `StripeElements` you can `destroy` the components before unmounting. I'm wondering if something similar needs to be done with `StripeCheckout` however there are no functions to do so. I can't find any documentation on this.

Why is `StripeCheckout` causing an exception to be thrown when routing/unmounting?

Comment: Which Vue version do you use? I guess the Lib is not compatible with Vuejs3. https://github.com/vue-stripe/vue-stripe/issues/289

Comment: I'm using Vue 3.2.13 but I thought it was compatible with Vue 3. Judging by that issue it seems not...
The issue mentions a couple other libraries that can be used. These are for `StripeElements` though. Do you know of any Vue 3 libraries for `StripeCheckout`?

Comment: https://github.com/vue-stripe/vue-stripe/issues/289#issuecomment-1310472503

Comment: Yeah those links are for StripeElements as opposed to StripeCheckout?

Comment: Sorry, know no others

Answer (score 0):

Ive had the same issue, have not found a proper solution yet but a temporary fix that works for me is

```
     <stripe-checkout
      v-if="readyToPay"
      ref="checkoutRef"
      mode="subscription"
      :pk="publishKey"
      :line-items="lineItems"
      :success-url="successUrl"
      :cancel-url="cancelUrl"
      @loading="(v) => (this.loading = v)"
    /> 
    ...
    <script>
     export default {
     name: "Packages",
     data(){return{readyToPay:false}}
     }
    </script>
```

and then have the submit function for the payment button trigger the stripe-checkout component to show and continue to payment after.

```
      async submit() {
      this.readyToPay = true;
      await this.$nextTick();
      ...
      }
```